# Secure way to connect to VNC from iPad

Tags: ipad, security, ssh, remote-desktop

've setup a VNC server in a computer and want to connect to if from another network. I first thought of doing port forwarding, but it did not work as I think for it to work I require to contact my ISP and this is not an option at the moment. So I decided to use a tool as ngrok (Free plan), set up in another computer (Which won't restart) the fowarding to my VNC computer. It did work, however it was clear multiple people tried to access it in the 20 minutes I was testing it (Via VNC portocol). So I am now trying to find a way to make it work securely. I was thinking of maybe using something like ssh encryption and forcing a particular public key, but I do not know how to do this on the iPad side. Thanks

I'm using TigerVNC on Ubuntu I'm using RealVNCViewer as the client on the iPad

[Changing this for forum](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1480298/secure-way-to-connect-to-vnc-from-ipad)

Comment: Is VNC protocol essential? If your question was how to connect securely from iPad to Ubuntu desktop, I would suggest TeamViewer (free for personal use).